# Python 3.6 Image crwaling

Tags: selenium-webdriver, web-crawler, python-3.6

I am crawling images from the Google image Search

I tried

1.Open the Chrome Driver with Selenium

2.Scroll down to end

3.Get image URL with BeautifulSoup and save Image

But it was a problem because the image was too small

So I found that there is an original image src

It is in the src(ends with ".jpg") of the irc_mi image class

But I do not know how to pull it out

I tried using find_all as the class name but it failed.

What should I do?

here are source codes

```
def Remainder_All_ImagesURLs_Google(searchText):

 def scroll_page():
    for i in range(7): 
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
        sleep(3) 

 def click_button():
    more_imgs_button_xpath = "//*[@id='smb']" 
    element = driver.find_element_by_xpath(more_imgs_button_xpath)
    element.click()
    sleep(3)


 def create_soup():
    html_source = driver.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_source, 'html.parser')
    return soup


 def find_imgs():
    soup = create_soup() 
    imgs_urls = [] 
    for img in soup.find_all('img'):
        try:
            if img['src'].startswith('http'): 
                imgs_urls.append(img['src'])
        except: 
            pass

    return imgs_urls


 driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/chromedriver.exe')

 driver.maximize_window()
 sleep(2)


 searchUrl = "https://www.google.com/search?q={}&site=webhp&tbm=isch".format(searchText)


 driver.get(searchUrl)

 try:
    scroll_page()
    click_button()
    scroll_page()


 except:
    click_button()
    scroll_page()

 imgs_urls = find_imgs()

 driver.close()

 return(imgs_urls)

def download_image(url,filename):
  full_name = str(filename)  + ".jpg"
  urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, 'C:/Python/Picture' +  full_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is beautiful soup wont find any source or href of image since its a java-script based function which returns source(src) hence my suggestion use selenium to click image tag and wait for image src and extract it 
use

```
element=driver.find_element_by_class_name("some_class")
element.click()
```

then search for image src